# Number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab \le 3600$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Find number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab\le 3600$ and $a,b \in N$

My attempt : Well, all $a,b \leqslant 60$ are solutions. These 3600 solutions. After that I have no idea how to count the number of remaining solutions...

I have a feeling that my approach is $very$ bad. But I had to give as it would be marked as off-topic.

Comment: What about $a=3600$ and $b=1$?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson:  that is one of the remaining ones.  We get it from the doubling of the case $a=1,b=3600$

Comment: @RossMillikan I was responding to his claim that $a,b\leq 60$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson:  I think the word "the" is extraneous.  He seemed to be saying that those are solutions, but knew there were more and wanted help counting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  First, you can count only those pairs where $a \lt b$, double them, and add one for $(60,60)$  We know $a \lt 60$.  How many are there for $a=1$?  How many are there for $a=2$?  Can you write an expression for general $a$?  Then add them up for $a$ from $1$ to $59$.

Comment: $2 \sum\lfloor{\frac{3600}{a}}\rfloor+1$

Comment: feels right?­­­­

Comment: Yes, that is correct.   Good work.

Comment: Thanks... Now let me guess... there is a nice way of summing this?

Comment: Well...not one wolfram alpha knows of.

Comment: No, I don't know one.  You can get close with the [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), but that doesn't include the floor function.  But you now have a $O(\sqrt n)$ problem, as you only have $60$ things to add up instead of $3600$

Comment: It is similar to the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem), which asks how many lattice points are in a circle.  You are asking how many are under a hyperbola.  I don't think either has a nice form.

Comment: Thanks.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: @Awesome: for a,b > 0, you mean $2 \sum _a^z \left\lfloor \frac{z^2}{a}\right\rfloor -z^2$ with z=60? so 30060 ?

Comment: @Awesome: or $\sum _a^{z^2} \sigma _0(a)$ see http://oeis.org/A175346

Comment: @WouterM. I have no idea what that means

Comment: @Awesome: sum of number of divisors of a for a = 1 .. 60^2 equals -(60^2)+2*sum of floor(60^2/a) for a = 1 .. 60; so the number of ordered pairs (a,b) with (a,b)>0 and a*b<=60^2 equals 30060; is this something that helps?

Comment: @WouterM. Can you please explain how did you get 30060?

Comment: Won't the answer be $\sum\frac{3600}{a}$ from a=1 to 3600?

Comment: take z=4 as example, so we're looking for pairs (a,b) such that a*b<=16, then we get 23 pairs: 1*1, 1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 1*5, 1*6, 1*7, 1*8, 1*9, 2*1, 2*2, 2*3, 2*4, 3*1, 3*2, 3*3, 4*1, 4*2, 5*1, 6*1, 7*1, 8*1, 9*1 ; Rows 1 to 9 have length 9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 and they form a symmetric tableau; we need only count the first 3 rows and take twice that but correcting for double-counting the square from 1*1 to 3*3; hence  -(3^2)+2*sum of floor(3^2/a) for a = 1 .. 3; I leave it to you to prove that this also equals sum of number of divisors of a for a = 1 .. z^2

Comment: ... got hit by the 5 min edit rule: take z=3 as example, so we're looking for pairs (a,b) such that a*b<=9, then we get 23 pairs etc ...

Comment: @WouterM., could you please write that out as an answer? I'd like to have a better understanding of what you are doing. I'm asking a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for the count of ordered pairs of integers (a,b) such that a*b <= n.
Set up a table in which the first row fixes a to 1: this allows b to run from 1 to n.
In the k'th row, we fix a to value k, so b runs from 1 to floor(n/k).
The table is obviously symmetrical across the diagonal (1,1), .. (q,q) with q=floor(sqrt(n))). This allows us to simplify the counting to a running from 1 to q, take twice that, and subtract the double counting of the square q^2.
Using Mathematica:
Table[q = Floor[Sqrt[n]]; 2*Sum[Floor[n/k], {k, q}] - q^2, {n, 16}]
or {1,3,5,8,10,14,16,20,23,27,29,35,37,41,45,50}
But, looking it up produces http://oeis.org/A006218 :
Table[ Sum[DivisorSigma[0,k],{k,n} ],{n,16}]  normally written as $\sum _k^n \sigma _0(k)$ alias the sum of (the count of divisors of k) for k running from 1 to n.
The challenge is to prove both counts to be equal.
Looking down the columns of the above table, we see that the entry in row k is 1 larger than that in row k-1 if floor(n/k) > floor(n/(k-1)), and that again happens only if k is a divisor of n. So, within row k, the entries in column j are 1 larger than in row k-1 exactly if j divides n. Not very challenging after all.